# Is toothpaste an issue on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cleaning

I heard that squeezing the toothpaste tube might be considered wringing. Does this have any basis?

Comment: No melacha is being done.

Comment: http://www.kosherimage.com/toothcare2.html

Comment: Yea,not anything about tube

Comment: I think it may be d'rabanon and come from memacheik (smoothing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some say yes, some say no.

The issue is not only wringing, but also whether the paste turning into froth is considered *nolad*, something new that came to be on Shabbat. For a comprehensive overview of the issues involved and which poskim have ruled what, see ***Yabia Omer* Vol. IV O"H #30**, where Rav Ovadia rules that it is permissible to brush your teeth using regular toothpaste on Shabbat.

For a summary of that responsum, here is the Yalkut Yosef 326:14:

> Some *Poskim* ruled that even someone who brushes teeth with toothpaste every day may not do so on Shabbat for various reasons. One reason given for this is that when one brushes, the toothpaste becomes frothy with suds, and therefore this is an act of *molid*. Another reason given is that vigorous brushing might cause the gums to bleed.
>
> Other *Poskim* ruled that it is permitted as long as one places the toothpaste directly into one's teeth and not on the toothbrush. Yet other *Poskim* ruled that even more leniently, permitting one to brush one's teeth on Shabbat just as one does on the weekdays and with regular toothpaste. They explained that it is not necessary to use special, liquid toothpaste, since brushing teeth is not an act of the *melakha* of *memare'ah*, nor is it an act of *molid*. Furthermore, this is not forbidden as an example of using medical treatments on Shabbat.
>
> In practice, anyone who would feel uncomfortable if he does not brush his teeth on Shabbat because of bad breath or some other reason may brush them. This applies, however, only to someone who regularly brushes his teeth so that he will not necessarily cause his gums to bleed on Shabbat.

Comment: any clue what Hacham Ovadia says regarding using bar soap on Shabbat?

Comment: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Cosmetics#Soap

Comment: @Ramin: Yes, he follows a responsum from the Rambam to argue that when it's necessary, like in a hospital, it can certainly be used. It's best to avoid it, but "there is no basis to protest against those who use it in all cases." See Yalkut Yosef 326:13